# Qt - Problem to Getting all source ( HTML code ) with qtNetworkAccesManager of a web page

Tags: html, qt, http

I have some difficulties with the QtNetworkAccesManager.

I want to fetch the source code from an URL. The problem is that I'm getting only parts of the HTML source code, but not all of it. Can you tell me, what I am missing?

```
void MyClass::importFromWeb()
{
    QUrl url = QUrl("https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html");
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager  = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &MyClass::onNetworkReply);
    response = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}

void MyClass::onNetworkReply()
{
   
    QFile* data = new QFile("test.txt");
    data->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QTextStream write(dat koa);
    write << response->readAll();
    data->close();
}
```

For example if i want to fetch the source code of "https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html", the result size of test.txt  is of 134 ko
However html code size when i'm doing a "ctrl+s" on the web site is of 192 ko.
So  is missing some source code but what and why ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide more details (i.e. specify what does not work, what you tried, what the output is so far, error logs etc.) otherwise it will be harder for others to understand what you want and to track down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice i edited my question , i don't know everything on the html and the http so i'm not understand the difference of result between the result of my code and a "ctrl +s" of the web site.